# Powers of prime factors of a positive integer $n$ in "Mathematica"?

Tags: functions, number-theory, factorization, prime-numbers

I would like to find the powers of a prime in the unique prime factorization of an $n$.  I want a function $f[n,p]$ such that $n,p$ are given and I need to know what the power of $p$ is. For instance

```
n=60;
f[n,2]=2;
f[n,3]=1;
f[n,5]=1;
f[n,7]=0;
```

Comment: maybe `f[n_, p_] := Cases[FactorInteger[n], {p, e_} :> e]`?

Comment: If you want efficiency when dealing with large inputs, just use division. `getPower[n_, p_ /; Abs[p] != 1] := 
 Module[{i = 0, q = n}, While[Divisible[q, p], i++; q /= p]; i]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really mean, as you say, that $n$ and $p$ are *given*, so you could simply use `IntegerExponent[n,p]`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Again (yes, it's happened before).

Answer (score 2):

```
f[n_, p_] := 
 Block[{s}, s = Select[FactorInteger[n], MemberQ[#, p] &]; 
  If[s == {}, 0, s[[1, 2]]]]
```

or

```
f[n_, p_] := First @ (Cases[FactorInteger[n], {p, e_} :> e] /. {} -> {0})
```

Then

```
f[60, 2]
f[60, 3]
f[60, 5]
f[60, 7]
```

> 2
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 0

```
f[11^17 13^15, 5]
f[11^17 13^15, 13]
```

> 0
>
> 15