# Prime factorization related functions: prime factor to its power and power of prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

[`FactorInteger`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorInteger.html) can be used to perform prime factorization:

```
FactorInteger[5^2 7^3 11^4]
```

Results in:

```
{{5,2},{7,3},{11,4}}
```

Is there a function that given an integer will return the value of a given prime factor raised to its power?

E.g. let's say the function is `F`:

```
F[5^2 7^3 11^4, 5]    returns: 5^2
F[5^2 7^3 11^4, 7]    returns: 7^3
F[5^2 7^3 11^4, 11]   returns: 11^4
```

Also, is there a function that will return the power of a given prime?

E.g. let's say the function is `G`:

```
G[5^2 7^3 11^4, 5]    returns: 2
G[5^2 7^3 11^4, 7]    returns: 3
G[5^2 7^3 11^4, 11]   returns: 4
```

Comment: Related: [129875](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129875/61597)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `G` is called `IntegerExponent[]` in *Mathematica*:

```
Table[IntegerExponent[5^2 7^3 11^4, k], {k, {5, 7, 11}}]
   {2, 3, 4}
```

You should now be able to use that function to write your function `F`.

Comment: Thank you J.M.!